# Make this function tacit

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I'd like to make this function point-free, in order to simplify it. I'm passing the length explicitly instead of computing it, since I also need it for other functions, and I'd like to compute it just once. I've manged to get rid of the target string parameter, but struggling with the other two.

```
-- Cycle with respect to whitespace (currently only spaces).
-- Given a source string and its length, and a longer target string
-- (which may contain spaces) match the source to target such that:
-- 1. both will have the same length
-- 2. spaces in the target string will remain spaces
-- 3. chars from the source string will be cycled
--
-- Example:
-- src: "ALLY", len: 4
-- target: "MEET AT DAWN"
-- Result: "ALLY AL LYAL"                  
cycleWS :: String -> Int -> String -> String
cycleWS str len = fst . (foldr (\x (s, n) -> if x == ' ' then (s ++ " ", n) else (s ++ [str !! (n `mod` len)], n + 1)) ("", 0))
```

Comment: How about making it simpler by breaking it into easy-to-understand pieces, instead?

Comment: Sure, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Well, how about a function to line up a string with the spaces in another string, plus `cycle`.

Comment: @ReidBarton thanks, implemented.

Comment: What if `length str != len`? There's no reason to pass the length as an explicit argument; just infer it from the given string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seriously doubt it that this particular function can be made more simple by writing it in a point-free style. For example, here's what I got from [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/):

```
cycleWS = ((fst .) .) . flip flip (([]), 0) . (foldr .) . flip flip snd . ((flip . (ap .)) .) . flip flip fst . ((flip . ((.) .) . flip (ap . (ap .) . (. ((,) . (++ " "))) . (.) . if' . (' ' ==))) .) . flip flip (1 +) . ((flip . (liftM2 (,) .) . flip ((.) . (++))) .) . flip flip ([]) . ((flip . ((:) .)) .) . (. flip mod) . (.) . (!!)
```

Comment: I wonder if `flip flip` can be eliminated since they cancel out?

Comment: @dimid No, they do not cancel out. Remember, function application is left associative, so e.g. `flip flip snd` is the same as `(flip flip) snd` and _not_ `flip (flip snd)`.

Answer (score 7):

Following @Reid Barton's suggestion:

```
-- Cycle with respect to whitespace (currently only spaces).
-- Given a source string and its length, and a longer target string
-- (which may contain spaces) match the source to target such that:
-- 1. both will have the same length
-- 2. spaces in the target string will remain spaces
-- 3. chars from the source string will be cycled
--
-- Example:
-- src: "ALLY", len: 4
-- target: "MEET AT DAWN"
-- Result: "ALLY AL LYAL"                  
cycleWS :: String -> String -> String
cycleWS = align . cycle

-- Align with respect to spaces.
-- Given two strings, source and target, align the source to target such that:
-- 1. both will have the same length
-- 2. spaces in the target string will remain spaces
-- Assume the source string is long enough 
align :: String -> String -> String
align [] _  = []
align _ [] = []
align (x:xs) (y:ys) = if isSpace y then y : align (x:xs) ys else x : align xs ys
```

Comment: You can use `isSpace` for more space characters.

Comment: By the way, this is far superior to the code you started out with. I'm allergic to `!!`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Is `!!` considered a code smell?

Comment: It's a partial function and it's also slow as molasses. The combination is terrible.